# Loading a CSS file to a new theme in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am making a new theme for WordPress using guide from this site https://www.taniarascia.com/developing-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch.

The writer of tutorial the says that using `<link href="" rel="stylesheet">`

> is not the most correct way to load scripts.

I am thinking to use `wp_enqueue_style()` and `add_action()` on function.php to load the .css file. I have already had three files, index.php, function.php, and style.css in my theme directory but I can't seem to make it work.

Below is the code I use to load the .css file:

```
<?php
  function enqueue_my_styles(){
  wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');
 }

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_styles' );

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your functions file named `functions.php` or `function.php`? This should be `functions.php` and is fundamental.

Your code looks correct, but could actually be shortened a little as in the `twentyfifteen` Wordpress template;

```
function twentyfifteen_scripts() {
    // Load our main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyfifteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentyfifteen_scripts' );
```

You'd use `get_template_directory_uri()` for loading a custom file within the template directory.

```
function my_custom_styles() {        
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom-style.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_styles' );
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the file name of function.php should be functions.php. It is totally a newbie mistake, my bad! Sorry and thank you so much for the extended lesson. I have been stuck here for quite several days.

Comment: No problem. Everybody has to start somewhere so keep at it. :)